# VSCode Could not establish connection to

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have tried the solutions from other post, i.e. change the SSH plugin version and also remove .vscode-server from the host, but nothing works

Always the same error message: **VSCode Could not establish connection to**

Full log:

```
[15:57:45.163] Log Level: 2
[15:57:45.199] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a22313027485554564saazadazdzadzadazzdf6f74222c22706f7274223a383838327d", attempt 1
[15:57:45.200] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[15:57:45.200] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[15:57:45.201] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"login.g100.someotherserver.com":"linux","10.20.30.43":"linux","10.25.12.148":"linux","82.180.155.13":"linux","109.106.241.239":"linux","89.117.117.15":"linux","149.100.159.118":"linux"}
[15:57:45.201] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[15:57:45.201] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[15:57:45.201] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[15:57:45.201] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[15:57:45.202] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[15:57:45.202] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[15:57:45.202] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[15:57:45.202] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[15:57:45.202] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[15:57:45.204] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[15:57:45.204] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[15:57:45.204] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[15:57:45.206] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {"login.g100.someotherserver.com":"/g100_work/uBS21_InfGer_0"}
[15:57:45.210] VS Code version: 1.81.1
[15:57:45.210] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.102.0
[15:57:45.210] win32 x64
[15:57:45.217] SSH Resolver called for host: root@10.25.12.148
[15:57:45.217] Setting up SSH remote "10.25.12.148"
[15:57:45.223] Using commit id "6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794" and quality "stable" for server
[15:57:45.227] Install and start server if needed
[15:57:45.235] Checking ssh with "C:\xampp7.3\php\ssh.exe -V"
[15:57:45.238] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\xampp7.3\php\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:57:45.238] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe -V"
[15:57:45.240] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:57:45.240] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe -V"
[15:57:45.241] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:57:45.242] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\ssh.exe -V"
[15:57:45.243] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:57:45.243] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\ssh.exe -V"
[15:57:45.245] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:57:45.245] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[15:57:45.248] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:57:45.248] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe -V"
[15:57:45.250] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:57:45.250] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[15:57:45.252] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:57:45.253] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[15:57:45.255] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[15:57:45.255] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[15:57:45.289] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[15:57:45.295] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 32136 -p 8882 "root@10.25.12.148" bash
[15:57:45.298] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:57:45.602] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:57:45.603] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[15:57:45.634] > Bad owner or permissions on C:\\Users\\aymer/.ssh/config
> Le processus a tenté d’écrire sur un canal inexistant.
[15:57:46.919] "install" terminal command done
[15:57:46.920] Install terminal quit with output: Le processus a tenté d’écrire sur un canal inexistant.
[15:57:46.920] Received install output: Le processus a tenté d’écrire sur un canal inexistant.
[15:57:46.921] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[15:57:46.923] Resolver error: Error: 
    at m.Create (c:\Users\aymer\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:584145)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\aymer\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:582705)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\aymer\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:681881)
    at async c:\Users\aymer\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:644110
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\aymer\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:647428)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\aymer\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:645160)
    at async c:\Users\aymer\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:720916
[15:57:46.934] ------

[15:58:50.180] Picking SSH host
[15:59:04.622] Selected root@10.25.12.148
```

I see this ** Bad owner or permissions on C:\Users\aymer/.ssh/config** error, but I have started VSCode as root, and still the same.

Any idea?

Thanks

[EDIT]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file explorer:

1. navigate to `C:\users\your.user.name\.ssh`
2. right-click on the file named `config` and click Properties
3. open the Security tab
4. check the list of "Groups or user names"

Only your specific user should have access to that file.  Click the "Edit" button to remove the other users.

You may have a similar issue with other files in that directory such as `id_xyz` identity files and or the `.ssh` folder itself.

Comment: Hello, I edited my post to show you the users in Properties, mine is the one starting with random... should I remove all the other ones including System ? Also, side question, I never created the user "Compte inconnu" myself, do you think I could have been hacked ?

Comment: I deleted all users except Random on all the files of the C:\users\aymer\.ssh folder, but I still have the issue. Also I noticed that VSCode looks into C:\users\aymer\.ssh (and not C:\users\Random\.ssh). I would like to authorize the access to the files to aymer (instead of to Random), but Windows says it cannot find the object "aymer" when I try to add it...

Comment: Ok, your solution was right except that you should have mentioned to ALSO change the right permissions for the parent folder (.shh)

Comment: @ailauli69 in the last sentence: "..and or the .ssh folder itself"